# How to find $\left(\sqrt{\theta^2+1}\right)\sin \beta$ when a rotating wheel goes up in an incline?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

A wheel of radius $r$ given in inches starts moving over an incline from point $O$ which is a tangential point. The wheel moves up in the incline due an exterior force. Assuming that the wheel stopped at point $T$ as indicated in the figure and the angle swept by the wheel is $\theta$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Find:

$$\left(\sqrt{\theta^2+1}\right)\sin \beta$$

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\cos\alpha-\theta\sin \alpha\\
2.&\sin \alpha+\theta\cos \alpha\\
3.&\cos\alpha+\theta\sin \alpha\\
4.&\sin\alpha - \theta \cos\alpha\\
\end{array}$

What's exactly the right way to approach this problem?
The part which confuses me the most is **how to use the information of the angle $\beta$ from the drawing?**

The reason for that is angle $beta$ is in the dotted line but not in the slope of the incline. Thus this is confusing.

It seems that the intended strategy is to use the radius of the wheel as an auxiliary variable to get the whole thing in terms of $\alpha$.

But how to do this methodically?. Can someone help me here?. What's exactly the right way to do this without much fuss?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As the wheel swept an angle $\theta$, $OT = r\theta$.

Now draw perpendiculars, $PT \perp OT$, $PR \perp OR$ .

We can observe that the angles $\angle POR = \pi - \beta$ and $\angle TPS = \alpha$.

The hypotenuse $OP = \sqrt{r^2+(r\theta)^2} = r\sqrt{1+\theta^2}$.

From triangle, PTS

[image]

$PT = r$, $ST = r\tan \alpha$, $PS = r\sec\alpha$

So, $OS = r\theta - r\tan\alpha$

Now

$\begin{align}\sin(\beta) &= \sin(\pi-\beta) = \frac{PR}{OP} = \frac{PS + SR}{OP} = \frac{PS + OS\sin\alpha}{OP}\\& = \frac{r(\sec\alpha+(\theta - \tan\alpha)\sin\alpha)}{r\sqrt{a+\theta^2}} = \frac{\theta\sin\alpha + \frac1{\cos\alpha} - \frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos\alpha}}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}} \\&=\frac{\theta\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}} \\
\text{Thus }&\boxed{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}\sin(\beta) = \cos\alpha+\theta\sin\alpha}
\end{align}$